# Programmatically print File of unknown Type by Path

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, printing

**Given**:

- We have a `list-based application` that allows you do `link a File` to an entry.
- `0...1 Relationship` from entry to file. (finding out if there is a file or not is my part, dont worry about that)
- Since we know who is going to use the application we can tell that most, but not all files, will be Microsoft Office (Word/Excel) Files.

**Need**:

- A way to `print these Files` (if windows knows how to do so)

**My Thoughts**:

Since we don't know the type  (.pdf, .exe) of the file we will have to `ask Windows` if its printable and `let Windows do the job` for us.

**My related code**:

There is no. I am not experienced working directly from application to Windows which is the reason why i don't know how to start it. I'd appreciate if you could link me some usefull guides about that, if you know some.

**Related Questions/Links**:

- [How can I ask Windows to print a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537823/how-can-i-ask-windows-to-print-a-document) : Haven't got it Working for VB yet

Comment: Following your related question, here is how to use ShellExecute in .Net : [ShellExecute equivalent in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258416/shellexecute-equivalent-in-net). You need to set ProccessStartInfo and Verb properly...

Answer (score 2):

Provided windows is set-up to print a file the following code should do exactly the same as right clicking on a file and selecting print:

```
    Dim process As System.Diagnostics.Process = New Process()
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
    startInfo.FileName = filename 
    startInfo.Verb = "Print" 'prints to default printer
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    process.StartInfo = startInfo
    process.Start()
```

Comment: That one looks promissing. What if i didn't want to use the default printer and use a user-selected printer instead ?

Comment: This code only prints to the default printer and with the printer's default settings. As I painfully found out trying to help another user(and failed).

Comment: @DavidWilson Yes it does. He also tells that in a code-comment. but is there a way do have a printerselection before printing?